# Is it possible to authenticate to a different Google Drive user in PyDrive?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, pydrive, flysystem-google-drive

I connected to my Google Drive using this code

!pip install -U -q PyDrive

```
from google.colab import files
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

I deleted the `adc.json` file, and when I run the code block again, it asks me to authenticate again, and use a different Google Drive user. However, when I upload a file, it's still uploading to the old google drive.

I even tried pip uninstalling and reinstalling pydrive, authenticate to new user again, upload file, and it still uploads to the old google drive.

I am wondering why this happens? Since the adc.json file is deleted and the runtime is reset, there should be nothing connecting to the old credentials. Perhaps some sort of bug?

Comment: You may try the menu "reset all runtime" then try again.

Comment: That would delete the file I am trying to upload unfortunately

Comment: another method is to use google.colab.drive.mount(...). It has a separate authentication to auth.authenticate_user()

Comment: great, it looks like I was able to log into the new account, but now I'm stuck and moving the file to the drive, I tried os.rename , shutil.move , shutil.copy, and  shutil.copyfile, they're all giving network error or OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported:

Comment: You can try `!cp file1 file2` or `!cp -r` for directory.